# What are these micro connectors called?

Tags: connector, identification

**Scenario:**

I've disassembled this USB camera and I had to cut a wire. I'd like a small male / female connector pair to put it back together.

- **Frayed wire** (right) is connected to the black plug (right/bottom) in the second photo. I would like to know the name of this male + female / polarized connector. *This connects to a USB 3 plug.*
- **White plug** (left) is connected to the white plug (left/top) in the second photo. I don't need to replace this but I would still like to know what it's called. *This connects to a servo motor.*

**Extra:**

On the *frayed wire* it's using a two row (2x3) connector but there are only 5 wires. I assume the 6th wire is the protective wrap around the outside of the wires?

[image]
[image]

Comment: White = JST connector - probably 2mm pitch. But you will need to do some measurements.

Comment: [Here's their catalog, once you have those measurements.](http://www.jst-mfg.com/index_e.php)

Comment: JST uses blade pins? @TomCarpenter

Comment: I picked up a set of 2-5 pin JST connectors and those work fine but I didn't find anything like the black connector. For now I'm just going to use a 2 pin + 4 pin for the 6 pin connector. Hopefully someone will come along with info on the 6 pin in my photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**White Connector**

2 pin JST-XHP Connector

**Black Connector**

Double Row 6 pin Servo Connector *(There's likely a much better name than this)*

## Also

There's this [list of connectors for small gauge wires](http://tech.mattmillman.com/info/crimpconnectors/)

Comment: "JST" isn't enough to identify it. Even the most common "JST" connectors come in two different types.